# db.collection is not a function on using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to work with mongodb and to insert some data but I am getting an error .
Here is the code .

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp', (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server');
  }
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB server');


  db.collection('Users').insertOne({
    name: 'Andrew',
    age: 25,
    location: 'Philadelphia'
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to insert user', err);
    }

    console.log(result.ops);
  });

  db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The native driver for MongoDB has changed what its `.connect()` method provides to you in recent versions.

[3.0](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#~connectCallback)

> connectCallback(error, client)

[2.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html#~connectCallback)

> connectCallback(error, db)

These being how your `(err, db) => { ... }` callback is defined in the documentation.

---

The [`.connect()` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) provides you a `MongoClient` instance. Including the database name in the connection address at least doesn't appear to change that.

You'll have to instead use the client's [`.db()` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html#db) to get a `Db` instance with collections.

```
const dbName = 'TodoApp';

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', (err, client) => {
  if (err) { ... }

  let db = client.db(dbName);

  db.collection('Users')...;
});
```